# compiled function not mapable

Tags: compile, map

I am currently working on speeding up a larger project and thus using FunctionCompile. I have come across the issue that a manual input of list elements produces a valid results, however if I try to map over a whole list, it just routes back to the uncompiled version. Is there a fix for this?
This is my compiled function which compiles fine and also works for single inputs:

```
f = FunctionCompile[
   Function[{Typed[vecA, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]], 
     Typed[vecB, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]], 
     Typed[dist, "Real64"], Typed[axis, "String"]},
    Module[
     {x, axiscount},
     axiscount = Switch[axis, "x", 1, "y", 2, "z", 3, _, 0];
     x = Table[0, 3];
     x[[axiscount]] = 1;
     Dot[vecA, x] - Dot[vecB, x] + 
      Sqrt[(Dot[vecB, x] - Dot[vecA, x])^2 - Norm[vecB - vecA]^2 + 
        dist^2]
     ]]];
```

Mapping does not work:

```
f[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], "x"] & /@ tmp
```

just jumps back to the uncompiled version.

However this works:

```
f[tmp[[1]][[1]], tmp[[1]][[2]], tmp[[1]][[3]], "x"]
```

I would really appreciate someone to help out.

**EDIT:**

As correctly pointed out I should state the definition of tmp. It is a list of lists which looks like this but is much longer:

```
tmp = {{{vecA11, vecA21, vecA31}, {vecB11, vecB21, vecB31}, 
   dist1}, {{vecA12, vecA22, vecA32}, {vecB12, vecB22, vecB32}, dist2}, 
  ...}
```

e.g.:

```
tmp = {{{-0.469967, -1.24125, 1.29046}, {-0.469967, -1.24125, 
    1.29046}, 
   3.6704}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 1.29046}, {-0.156997, -0.416589, 
    0.433353}, 
   4.1602}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 
    1.29046}, {0.283536, -0.836902, -0.942764}, 
   4.0052}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 1.29046}, {-0.198278, 1.06228, 
    0.708401}, 
   4.0052}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 
    1.29046}, {-0.401773, -0.426136, -1.68817}, 
   3.3852}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 
    1.29046}, {1.29976, -0.479835, -1.12695}, 
   3.3852}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 
    1.29046}, {0.27349, -1.92788, -1.01604}, 
   3.3852}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 1.29046}, {-0.529514, 1.23723, 
    1.73582}, 
   3.3852}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 1.29046}, {-0.901259, 1.54273, 
    0.0235547}, 
   3.3852}, {{-0.469967, -1.24125, 1.29046}, {0.800999, 1.48636, 
    0.582325}, 
   3.3852}, {{-0.156997, -0.416589, 0.433353}, {-0.469967, -1.24125, 
    1.29046}, 
   4.1602}, {{-0.156997, -0.416589, 0.433353}, {-0.156997, -0.416589, 
    0.433353}, 
   4.65}, {{-0.156997, -0.416589, 
    0.433353}, {0.283536, -0.836902, -0.942764}, 
   4.495}, {{-0.156997, -0.416589, 0.433353}, {-0.198278, 1.06228, 
    0.708401}, 
   4.495}, {{-0.156997, -0.416589, 
    0.433353}, {-0.401773, -0.426136, -1.68817}, 
   3.875}, {{-0.156997, -0.416589, 
    0.433353}, {1.29976, -0.479835, -1.12695}, 
   3.875}, {{-0.156997, -0.416589, 
    0.433353}, {0.27349, -1.92788, -1.01604}, 3.875}}
```

Comment: I don't see the definition of `tmp`

Comment: Please provide some actual data rather than just a template for data.

Comment: Are you looking for `f[##, "x"]& @@@ tmp` ?

Comment: @MarcoB this syntax does not do anything, I just get tmp as output

Comment: @FreetimeCoder Are you sure? This is what I get: https://imgur.com/a/XhhI9ad

Comment: @MarcoB I now figured out what the problem is. For a specific element the output is a complex number which (in the uncompiled version) gets removed later. How to compensate for that or how to allow such an output for the compiled version?

Comment: @FreetimeCoder What is the specific input that generates that output?

Comment: @MarcoB the 48th element of the full tmp is: {{-0.401773, -0.426136, -1.68817}, {-0.529514, 1.23723, 1.73582}, 3.1} which results in a complex output. For all other elements of the list it works and is also much faster than the uncompiled version.

Comment: To get a complex result from compiled Sqrt, make sure the argument type is declared to be complex.